# How to stop/kill airflow scheduler started in daemon mode

Tags: linux, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I and new to airflow and accidentally started airflow scheduler in daemon mode. Now, I want to kill the scheduler and possibly restart it. I tried doing

```
    sudo kill -9 <list of pids>
    pkill <name>
```

nothing is happening. When I run

```
    ps aux | grep 'airflow scheduler'
```

I see these entries:

```
    user1   2907  6.0  1.0 329788 62996 ?        Sl   17:37   1:26 /users/user1/anaconda2/bin/python /users/user1/anaconda2/bin/airflow scheduler -D
    user1   2909  0.0  0.9 327576 58948 ?        Sl   17:37   0:00 /users/user1/anaconda2/bin/python /users/user1/anaconda2/bin/airflow scheduler -D
    user1   2910  0.0  0.9 327576 58944 ?        Sl   17:37   0:00 /users/user1/anaconda2/bin/python /users/user1/anaconda2/bin/airflow scheduler -D
    user1   2911  0.0  0.9 327576 58944 ?        Sl   17:37   0:00 /users/user1/anaconda2/bin/python /users/user1/anaconda2/bin/airflow scheduler -D
```

...and so on for 35 lines with different pids.

Any recommendation as to how I can stop/kill airflow scheduler without restarting my machine. I have also checked the pid file for scheduler and tried killing that pid but no effects.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Did you try killing everything with airflow using something like
ps -ef | grep airflow | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9

Answer (score 15):

Unfortuntely

```
kill $(ps -ef | grep "airflow scheduler" | awk '{print $2}')
```

I was not able to find a clean solution.

Also looking into the code

https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/bin/cli.py

Answer (score 6):

Go to the airflow directory where the pid file is and use:
`cat airflow-scheduler.pid | xargs kill`

Answer (score 1):

To kill airflow webserver and scheduler, you can use below command

If you have supervisord configured for airflow, then stop it first

```
supervisorctl stop all

kill -9 `ps aux | grep airflow | awk '{print $2}'`
```

Comment: It worked to me, i just ran the second line

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is:

```
/usr/bin/rm -f ${AIRFLOW_HOME}/airflow-scheduler.pid
/usr/bin/pkill -f "airflow-scheduler"
```

Please note better to remove older daemon .pid file; to avoid any issue while restarting on daemon mode.

You can also see: https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/77

```
/bin/sh -c 'PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin  mPPID=`cat ${AIRFLOW_HOME}/airflow-scheduler.pid`;ps -o pid= --ppid $mPPID | xargs kill -15 && kill -15 $mPPID && rm -f ${AIRFLOW_HOME}/airflow-scheduler.pid'"
```

But this command relies on parent PID (.pid file) so if parent process was removed and child processes are still running it won't work.

So in my opinion accepted answer is the best. Or if you have installed use pkill

If using any monitoring service i.e monit like in the github link.
Valid stop command would be:

```
gPPID=`ps -ef | /usr/bin/grep 'airflow scheduler' | /usr/bin/grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' `; echo $gPPID; | xargs kill -15 && rm -f ${AIRFLOW_HOME}/airflow-scheduler.pid
```

Answer (score 0):

```sh
cd ~/airflow
cat airflow-scheduler.pid | xargs kill
```

Comment: Code only answers are not as useful as answers that document the code or have an detailed explanation on why this code is the solution to the question.